# Issues with special characters and symbols while storing and parsing HTML in java

Tags: java, selenium, special-characters

I am using Selenium to test an e-commerce application. I need to check the items listed on selecting a category on the listing page match with items in the Database. So I am accessing pages using selenium and storing the page source in a text file. I later parse this text file using HTMLCleaner and JSoup to get the field I wish to validate with the DB.

However, I noticed that some products listed on the page use special characters like ™ , ® and so on which are not stored/retrieved correctly and displayed as question marks.

Code I am using to store the page source:

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try
{
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath+"/"+filename+".txt"));
    writer.write(driver.getPageSource());
}
catch ( IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        writer.close( );
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Retrieving and parsing file

```
Document htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(fileSavedPreviously,"ISO-8859-1");
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(fileSavedPreviously);

try {
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties())
        .createDOM(tagNode);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//rest of the parsing....
```

Comment: The encoding you use is probably not correct. You should retrieve it from HTTP header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the encoding for the stream writer :

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fullpath), "UTF-8"));
```

And provide the same one to the parser :

```
Document htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(fileSavedPreviously, "UTF-8");
```

To get the encoding of the page, execute `document.inputEncoding` in the browser console.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the constructors of `FileWriter` it will use the default charset which doesn't cover those special characters obviously if you face such issue so you should instead use the constructors of `OutputStreamWriter` to define explicitly the character encoding as next:

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(String.format("%s/%s.txt", filepath, filename)), charsetName
    )
);
```

Since `ISO-8859-1` covers ® but not ™, you should use a unicode charset such as `UTF-8` and set it in both places where you write your content and where you read it.

Comment: Nice and informative, could do with a bit more code. The used "ISO-8859-1" (Latin-1) could be replaced by "Windows-1252" (Windows Latin-1) which is what browsers use when they see "ISO-8859-1". There ™ is present. (Of course best/universal would be UTF-8.)